# TBE audio skipping in Gear VR app on Galaxy S6 with Android 6.0.1 but not 5.1.1

Tags: android, audio, unity-game-engine, galaxy, gear-vr

I'm developing a Gear VR app in Unity which plays a stereoscopic 360 video in sync with spatialized TBE audio.

It's developed in Unity 5.5.1p3, using Oculus Utilities v1.11.0 and OVRPlugin v1.11.0.

It uses the Two Big Ears v0.9.9 plugin to play a 29Mb .tbe audio file (located in the project's StreamingAssets folder).

We've tested on several Samsung phones:

- Galaxy S7: *no issues*
- Galaxy S6 with Android **5.1.1**: *no issues*
- Galaxy S6 with Android **6.0.1**: *audio skips frequently, making a "chirp"*

This was replicated on several S6s by flashing the ROM to downgrade the OS.

We've tried numerous experiments to narrow down the issue, including:

1. disabling video playback: *no effect*
2. reducing TBSpatDecoder volume: *this has resolved clipping issues on previous projects; but, no effect here*
3. changing Unity's DSP Buffer Size to "Best Performance": *this reduced skipping slightly*

According to adb logcat, the app is running consistently at 58-60fps.

Any insight on this issue or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Evan

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a few months back. I managed to resolve it by using latest version of TBAudioEngine (0.9.95) and lowering the decoder's volume from 1 to 0.75. 
You can download the latest version here: https://facebook360.fb.com/spatial-workstation/